# Image gets cropped a little bit, just in IE

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, cross-browser

For some reason, the image below looks it is cropped just a little from the right side when I open the image in IE, otherwise in FireFox/Chrome is looks absolutely fine

[image]

Could you please tell me why is this happening?

---

[image: Image in IE] Image in IE

[image: Image in FireFoz] Image in FireFox

---

Regards
Zeeshan

Comment: Looks fine to me in IE 7/8/9.

Comment: I tried in IE 8, and the image is cropped just a little bit on the right.

Comment: Yes, it is cropped in IE. I am bit curious for the answer.

Comment: i zooming your image in ie. top, right and bottom not cut perfectly.

Comment: i got the same issue in ie10 only

Answer (score 0):

Hi I dont have the exact solution but I observed some thing.

Please use the below HTML snippet.

```
<body>        
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 200px; border-color:yellow;">
         <img src="IE_Bug.gif" alt="IE_Bug.gif" style="width:90%; 
           border-width: 3px; border-color:red;">
    </div>
</body>
```

Now open the HTML file both in Mozilla Firefox and InternetExplorer.

Notice the image in firfox carefully. You may notice that at the right side when the dark moving part of image crosses there is a blink effect in the image. Which effect is not there in IE. Also If we will increase the width of image to 110% then in IE the cropping seems to be vanished. At 110% width it appears like the right side border of image little thicker.

Please let me know if someone can find something interesting.:)